# How to install multiple python packages at once using pip 

Tags: python, pip

I know it's an  easy way of doing it but i didn't find it neither here nor on google. 
So i was curious if there is a way to install multiple packages using pip. 
Something like:

```
pip install progra1 , progra2 ,progra3 ,progra4 .
```

or:

```
pip install (command to read some txt containing the name of the modules)
```

Answer (score 500, accepted):

For installing multiple packages on the command line, just pass them as a space-delimited list, e.g.:

```
pip install wsgiref boto
```

For installing from a text file, then, from `pip install --help`:

> -r FILENAME, --requirement=FILENAME
>
> Install all the packages listed in the given requirements file.  This option can be used multiple times.

Take a look at [the pip documentation regarding requirements files](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files) for their general layout and syntax - note that you can generate one based on current environment / site-packages with `pip freeze` if you want a quick example - e.g. (based on having installed `wsgiref` and `boto` in a clean virtualenv):

```
$ pip freeze
boto==2.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: "space-delimited list" does not seem to work for me if there are dependencies between the packages, eg:
`sudo -H pip install setuptools trezor` causes this error: "Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Please install setuptools.".  Instead, I need to run as 2 separate commands.

Comment: Does this `pip install wsgiref boto` install the libraries with their dependencies as well?

Answer (score 149):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and in the requirements.txt file you put your modules in a list, with one item per line.

- Django=1.3.1
- South>=0.7
- django-debug-toolbar

Comment: How can I do the same using conda? any idea? conda intsall -r requirements.txt does not work.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802939/install-only-available-packages-using-conda-install-yes-file-requirements-t

Comment: Do you have to specify the version #?  In other words, if you just put `Django` on one line, would it automatically install the latest version?

Comment: You don't have to specify a version number, and generally don't need to, though which version exactly `pip` then installs is sometimes hard to predict, especially if you have configured `pip` with multiple source indices and/or configuration options which constrain which packages can be installed. A common need is to specify a minimum version requirement, like `pip >= 9.0`

Comment: You need a double == rather than one =

Answer (score 28):

On the command line if you have a few packages to install, You may just do

```
pip install <package_1> <package_2>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 20):

You can install packages listed in a text file called [requirements file](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files).
For example, if you have a file called `req.txt` containing the following text:

```
Django==1.4
South==0.7.3
```

and you issue at the command line:

```
pip install -r req.txt
```

pip will install packages listed in the file at the specific revisions.

Comment: Must I specify the version or can I just have `Django` on its own line and expect to get the latest version? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following steps:

**Step 1:** Create a requirements.txt with list of packages to be installed. If you want to copy packages in a particular environment, do this

```
pip freeze >> requirements.txt
```

else store package names in a file named `requirements.txt`

**Step 2:** Execute pip command with this file

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Complementing the other answers, you can use the option `--no-cache-dir` to disable caching in pip. My virtual machine was crashing when installing many packages at once with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. What solved for me was:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place multiple name together separated by a white space like

```
C:\Users\Dell>pip install markdown django-filter

#c:\Users\Dell is path in my pc this can be anything on yours
```

this installed markdown and django-filter on my device. [image]

Comment: Doesn't add anything new, compared to the already accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

give the same command as you used to give while installing a single module only pass it via space delimited format

Answer (score 0):

in the Jupyter kernel :

```
!py -3.11 -m pip install numpy pandas persiantools
```

Comment: There is an more modern user-friendly and consistent way inside Jupyter. In your example case, you'd run `%pip install numpy pandas persiantools`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) about the modern magic install commands for use inside cells in Jupyter notebooks that insure installation in the proper environment underlying the kernel. Please recommend current best practices.

Comment: I think this is a very inefficient way to install multiple packages i.e. using a requirements file. An environment file to install using conda i.e .XML environment file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).