# Error importing Seaborn module in Python: "ImportError: cannot import name utils"

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, seaborn

I am trying to import seaborn into python (using 2.7) using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math as math
from pylab import rcParams

%matplotlib inline
```

and getting the following error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-bd3d27f3b137> in <module>()
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 import seaborn as sns
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import math as math

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>()
      2 from .utils import *
      3 from .palettes import *
----> 4 from .linearmodels import *
      5 from .distributions import *
      6 from .timeseries import *

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seaborn\linearmodels.py in <module>()
     19 from .external.six.moves import range
     20 
---> 21 from . import utils
     22 from . import algorithms as algo
     23 from .palettes import color_palette

ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

What is the cause of this error, and how can the problem be fixed?

Comment: Is there a file `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py`? Probably not, so you may have an incorrect version of `seaborn` (too old?) installed.

Comment: Thanks Evert - this file exists.  I have the latest version of seaborn (Nov 2014), it all came bundled with my python download.  Is it possible that  this seaborn version isn't compatible with 2.7?

Comment: In that case, I don't know; I definitely can't reproduce your problem. Can you try the following from the very simplest Python shell (*not* IPython, just Python): `>>> import seaborn`?

Comment: I've opened up IDLE and entered >>> import seaborn.  No error messages.  Interesting!  Should I uninstall & reinstall do you think?

Comment: Sometimes uninstall/install works, but it may also be a local configuration issue with IPython, and those files are probably not removed when uninstall IPython. Have you tried the same `import seaborn` by itself in IPython? If it fails there, then something is iffy in IPython's configuration; though the relative import syntax as shown by the traceback looks correct.

Comment: Hi Evert, thanks for all of your help.  I was able to import it into just IPython (via the cmd function) and it worked there.  I then exited this, opened IPython Notebook and was then able to import seaborn.  I had tried it separately in Notebook previously but it did not work.  I tried it again separately today in Notebook and it has now worked.  Not sure what happened but I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.  I think stepping through your suggestions may have 'cleaned' the system and allowed the import.

Comment: Magic ;-). Sometimes, a compiled `*.pyc` file that doesn't get recompiled may mess up things, though that doesn't make much sense here. Clearing all `*.pyc` then helps, but here, I wouldn't really know.

Comment: Thanks - I would upvote you but I don't have enough rep to do so.  Am really grateful for you taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 41):

I had faced the same problem. Restarting the notebook solved my problem.

If that doesn't solve the problem, you can try this

```
pip install seaborn
```

**Edit**

As few people have posted in the comments, you can also use

```
python -m pip install seaborn
```

Plus, as per https://bugs.python.org/issue22295 it is a better way because in this case, you can specify which version of python (python3 or python2) to use for running `pip`

Comment: @Schütze Have you tried restarting the notebook? Can you try with pip install? pip3 works for me, no problem.

Comment: Ah, I actually had to add `sudo` in my case.

Comment: If you get the error `ImportError: cannot import name main`, use `sudo python2 -m pip install seaborn` or `sudo python3 -m pip install seaborn` depending on whether you are using Python 2 or 3.

Comment: Restarting and then installing package seaborn in pyCharam solved my problem.

Comment: For me it helped with `python -m pip install seaborn` for Python 3.6.8 and 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 9):

As @avp says the bash line `pip install seaborn` should work
I just had the same problem and and restarting the notebook didn't seem to work but running the command as jupyter line magic was a neat way to fix the problem without restarting the notebook

Jupyter Code-Cell:

```
%%bash
pip install seaborn
```

Comment: This worked! Amazing! Any clue as to why installing seaborn with conda from the terminal, then restarting the notebook didn't work, whereas this worked?

Comment: Good to hear. It was just a lucky guess ;)

Comment: These days you can simply use `%pip install seaborn` in a cell. No other line needed if you use **the magic install command that insures it installs in the same environment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running**. There's a conda magic install equivalent. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands you can use from inside notebooks for most installs in modern Jupyter.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I am using iPython. pip or conda by itself did not work for me but when I use !conda it did work.

```
!conda install seaborn
```

Comment: This is now outdated & not best practice. Avoid the exclamation point with install commands inside modern Jupyter (not Colab); see [[the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more on why.  See [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure installation in the proper environment in use by the notebook.

Answer (score 5):

If your python version is 2.+, you can type below code to the terminal :

```
pip install seaborn
```

if python version is 3+, type below:

```
pip3 install seaborn
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and I solved it and the explanation is as follow:

If the Seaborn package is not installed in anaconda, you will not be able to update it, namely,
if in the Terminal we type: conda update seaborn

it will fail showing:
"PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: 'seaborn' Package 'seaborn' is not installed in /Users/yifan/anaconda"

Thus we need to install seaborn in anaconda first by typing in Terminal:
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda seaborn

Then the seaborn will be fetched and installed in the environment of anaconda, namely in my case, /Users/yifan/anaconda

Once this installation is done, we will be able to import seaborn in python.

Side note, to check and list all discoverable environments where python is installed in anaconda, type in Terminal:
conda info --envs

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by looking at sys.path (the path for finding modules) while in ipython and noticed that I was in a special environment (because I use conda).

so i went to my terminal and typed "source activate py27"  is my python 2.7 environment. and then "conda update seaborn", restarted my jupyter kernel, and then all was good.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue with Seaborn.
I uninstalled python, anaconda and reinstalled anaconda 4.1.1 with python 3.6. After that installed seaboarn again

```
>>>conda install seaborn
```

And it worked. If you are still facing issue, I would recommend you doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same importing problem reinstalling to seaborn package with

conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda seaborn

by typing  the command on a Windows command console   Afterwards I could  then import seaborn successfully  when I launched the IPython Notebook via on Anaconda launcher.

On the other failed way launching the IPython Notebook via Anaconda folder did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem may not be associated with Seaborn but Utils package which may not be installed

> sudo pip uninstall requests

and reinstalling, it no longer would work at all.
Luckily, dnf install python-requests fixed the whole thing...

Also check for utils package is installed or not

You can install package using

> sudo pip install utils

Check this link [Python ImportError: cannot import name utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096364/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils)

Answer (score 1):

It seams that missing dependency of **python-dev**, install **python-dev** and then try to install seaborn, if you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev -y
pip install seaborn
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a problem with the scipy package, just `pip uninstall scipy` and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install seaborn
```

is also solved my problem in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend that you install Anaconda and then use the "pip install seaborn" command from the Lab Jupyter IDE. It should work. It seems that the package is already pre-installed on Lab Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete package whl file in 'C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages'
2. pip uninstlal scipy and seaborn
3. pip install scipy nd seaborn agaian

it worked for 4, win10, anaconda

Answer (score 0):

upgrade(!) the seaborn module

```
python -m pip install --upgrade seaborn
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I was using a conda environment, and did a pip install, so i did

```
python3 -m pip uninstall seaborn
```

and then instaled it using conda with

```
conda install -c anaconda seaborn
```

solved the error for me, hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

You can try using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/). It works for both 2.7 as well as 3.6. You can install it by running:

`pip install seaborn`