# Using Scipy pearsonr function with Python 3

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I've written a script to calculate the pearsons R coeficient and used it many times.

I'm importing the pearsonr function like this:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
```

The script runs without issue on Python 2.7. After upgrading to Python 3.4 the same script returns this error:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 338, in <module>
from .stats import *

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 188, in <module>
from . import futil

ImportError: cannot import name 'futil'
```

Is a WinPython vs Anaconda thing? Any ideas what I should be doing differently?

Comment: Some other questions such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313081/error-importing-seaborn-in-ipython-notebook-working-in-ipython) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167783/failure-scipy-testing-importerror-dll-load-failed) suggest it can be due to a broken scipy install.  Can you uninstall and reinstall scipy, or look for lingering .pyc files?

Comment: `conda remove scipy`,  `pip uninstall scipy`, `conda install -f scipy` will probably solve this.

Answer (score 0):

hello the main root cause is unknown to me but I resolved it as:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
```

Comment: Solving an import-related problem 6 years later, when scipy has been updated many times, is hardly helpful.