# Python ImportError: cannot import name utils

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm having this issue running a script and it looks like it missed some dependencies, but as you can see below. After installing the missing libraries, it doesn't make any sense.

```
[ericfoss@maverick-fossum-ddns-net packages]$ python -c "import utils"
[ericfoss@maverick-fossum-ddns-net packages]$ python -c "import requests"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from . import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
[ericfoss@maverick-fossum-ddns-net packages]$
```

Any idea why `utils` can be imported, but `requests` can't?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, after `pip uninstall requests` and reinstalling, it would no longer work. Luckily, `pip install python-requests' fixed the whole thing...

Comment: DO not install python-requests - that package has been hijacked --

Answer (score 7):

Check if Requests requirements are satisfied:

```
$ pip show requests
...
Requires: certifi, idna, chardet, urllib3
```

I hit the same error but I was missing `idna`. After installing it the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when running Jupyter Lab:

```
$ jupyter-lab --ip 0.0.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
  File "/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .handlers import add_handlers, LabConfig
  File "/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/handlers.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .listings_handler import ListingsHandler, fetch_listings
  File "/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/listings_handler.py", line 17, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from . import utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from partially initialized module 'requests' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/gtholpadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/__init__.py)
```

`requests` was already installed when I got this error. I tried `pip install -U requests` and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We may see the **unable to import utils** error in multiple contexts.
I got this error message when I was migrating scripts from python 2 to 3. 
I used the inbuilt python migration automated tool to change the file that is causing the import error using the command `2to3 -w filename`
This has resolved the error because the import utils is not back supported by python 3 and we have to convert that code to python 3.

Answer (score -11):

utils package is not installed

You can install package using

```
sudo pip install utils
```

Comment: As you can see in the question, `utils` imports just fine.

Comment: The missing utils here is from the requests package, installing `utils` packages from pip won't help here.