# ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'

Tags: python, python-3.x

after installing utils through pip i can import utils but when ever i try:

```
from utils import utils, helpers
from builders import model_builder
```

I got error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'

[image: as you can see in the screenshot]

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096425/7841468

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python ImportError: cannot import name utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096364/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils)

Comment: what are you trying to use ? the package `utils` doesn't have a module `utils`... Try simply `import utils`. Does it work then ?