# Unable to import process_tweets from utils

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

Thanks for looking into this, I have a python program for which I need to have `process_tweet` and `build_freqs` for some NLP task, `nltk` is installed already and `utils` **wasn't** so I installed it via `pip install utils` but the above mentioned two modules apparently weren't installed, the error I got is standard one here,

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'process_tweet' from
'utils' (C:\Python\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)
```

what have I done wrong or is there anything missing?
Also I referred [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096364/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils) but it didn't help.

Comment: where did you get this from? That you have to import `process_tweet` from `utils`? Are you following a tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily access any source code with ??, for example in this case: process_tweet?? (the code above from deeplearning.ai NLP course custome utils library):

```
def process_tweet(tweet):
"""Process tweet function.
Input:
    tweet: a string containing a tweet
Output:
    tweets_clean: a list of words containing the processed tweet

"""
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
stopwords_english = stopwords.words('english')
# remove stock market tickers like $GE
tweet = re.sub(r'\$\w*', '', tweet)
# remove old style retweet text "RT"
tweet = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', tweet)
# remove hyperlinks
tweet = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', tweet)
# remove hashtags
# only removing the hash # sign from the word
tweet = re.sub(r'#', '', tweet)
# tokenize tweets
tokenizer = TweetTokenizer(preserve_case=False, strip_handles=True,
                           reduce_len=True)
tweet_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet)

tweets_clean = []
for word in tweet_tokens:
    if (word not in stopwords_english and  # remove stopwords
            word not in string.punctuation):  # remove punctuation
        # tweets_clean.append(word)
        stem_word = stemmer.stem(word)  # stemming word
        tweets_clean.append(stem_word)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are following the NLP course on deeplearning.ai, then I believe the utils.py file was created by the instructors of that course, for use within the lab sessions, and shouldn't be confused with the usual utils.

Comment: Yes Indeed, Do you have that implementation, I need to do it on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, It should work:

```
def process_tweet(tweet):
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
stopwords_english = stopwords.words('english')
tweet = re.sub(r'\$\w*', '', tweet)
tweet = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', tweet)
tweet = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', tweet)
tweet = re.sub(r'#', '', tweet)
tokenizer = TweetTokenizer(preserve_case=False,        strip_handles=True,reduce_len=True)
tweet_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet)

tweets_clean = []
for word in tweet_tokens:
    if (word not in stopwords_english and  
            word not in string.punctuation): 
        stem_word = stemmer.stem(word)  # stemming word
        tweets_clean.append(stem_word)

return tweets_clean
```

Comment: It did work, however utils should have these functions right, so why did'nt it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need to use `process_tweet` as all. The code in the course is just a shortcut to summarize everything you do from the beginning to the stemming step; hence, just ignore the step and just print out the `tweet_stem` to see the difference between original text and preprocessed text.

Comment: Could you please link to the course or the code to give more context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
def preprocess_tweet(tweet):


# cleaning
tweet = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+','',tweet)

tweet = re.sub(r'https?://[^\s\n\r]+', '', tweet)

tweet = re.sub(r'#', '',tweet)
tweet= re.sub(r'@', '',tweet)

# tokenization

token = TweetTokenizer(preserve_case=False, strip_handles=True,reduce_len=True)

tweet_tokenized = token.tokenize(tweet)

# STOP WORDS

stopwords_english = stopwords.words('english')
tweet_processed = []

for word in tweet_tokenized:
    if (word not in stopwords_english and
       word not in string.punctuation):
        
        tweet_processed.append(word)
        
# stemming 
tweet_stem = []

stem = PorterStemmer()

for word in tweet_processed:
    stem_word = stem.stem(word)
    tweet_stem.append(stem_word)
    
    
    
return tweet_stem
```

**Input and Output**

[image: Input and Expected Output]

Answer (score 0):

This should help you all the way through.

```
import re
import string
import numpy as np

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer


def process_tweet(tweet):
    """Process tweet function.
    Input:
        tweet: a string containing a tweet
    Output:
        tweets_clean: a list of words containing the processed tweet
    """
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    stopwords_english = stopwords.words('english')
    # remove stock market tickers like $GE
    tweet = re.sub(r'\$\w*', '', tweet)
    # remove old style retweet text "RT"
    tweet = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', tweet)
    # remove hyperlinks
    tweet = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', tweet)
    # remove hashtags
    # only removing the hash # sign from the word
    tweet = re.sub(r'#', '', tweet)
    # tokenize tweets
    tokenizer = TweetTokenizer(preserve_case=False, strip_handles=True,
                               reduce_len=True)
    tweet_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet)

    tweets_clean = []
    for word in tweet_tokens:
        if (word not in stopwords_english and  # remove stopwords
                word not in string.punctuation):  # remove punctuation
            # tweets_clean.append(word)
            stem_word = stemmer.stem(word)  # stemming word
            tweets_clean.append(stem_word)

    return tweets_clean


def build_freqs(tweets, ys):
    """Build frequencies.
    Input:
        tweets: a list of tweets
        ys: an m x 1 array with the sentiment label of each tweet
            (either 0 or 1)
    Output:
        freqs: a dictionary mapping each (word, sentiment) pair to its
        frequency
    """
    # Convert np array to list since zip needs an iterable.
    # The squeeze is necessary or the list ends up with one element.
    # Also note that this is just a NOP if ys is already a list.
    yslist = np.squeeze(ys).tolist()

    # Start with an empty dictionary and populate it by looping over all tweets
    # and over all processed words in each tweet.
    freqs = {}
    for y, tweet in zip(yslist, tweets):
        for word in process_tweet(tweet):
            pair = (word, y)
            if pair in freqs:
                freqs[pair] += 1
            else:
                freqs[pair] = 1

    return freqs
```

All utils modules you need is above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_tweet(tweet):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    stopwords_english = stopwords.words('english')
    # remove stock market tickers like $GE
    tweet = re.sub(r'\$\w*', '', tweet)
    # remove old style retweet text "RT"
    tweet = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', tweet)
    # remove hyperlinks
    tweet = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', tweet)
    # remove hashtags
    # only removing the hash # sign from the word
    tweet = re.sub(r'#', '', tweet)
    # tokenize tweets
    tokenizer = TweetTokenizer(preserve_case=False, strip_handles=True,reduce_len=True)
    tweet_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet)

    tweets_clean = []
    for word in tweet_tokens:
        if (word not in stopwords_english and  # remove stopwords
               word not in string.punctuation):  # remove punctuation
            # tweets_clean.append(word)
            stem_word = stemmer.stem(word)  # stemming word
            tweets_clean.append(stem_word)
            return tweet
```

Comment: It would be much better if you provide more supporting information to your answer.