# Seaborn not installing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I was trying to import seaborn in Jupyter notebook on a Mac. This used to work fine, but for some reason, it keeps giving me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkZeK.png) now

I have tried to reinstall seaborn and pandas. I also restarted my notebook, but that didn't work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: A simple stopping of a jupyter-notebook session and restarting it should work. Also, I would suggest referring the following link, which depicts 'similar' problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using a correct kernel on Jupyter?
Do you install the packages on the terminal or inside the notebook?
Run `print(help(modules)` to see if you have all packages that you were supposed to have.