# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wget'

Tags: python, wget

I am trying to import wget in my python 3.8 running in the notebook. I tried pip install wget it says "Requirement already satisfied: wget in c:\users\mahmu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (3.2)" but getting the following error when trying to import it:

```
if os.name=='nt':
    !pip install wget
    import wget
```

Output

```
Collecting wget
  Using cached wget-3.2.zip (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for wget, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: wget
    Running setup.py install for wget: started
    Running setup.py install for wget: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed wget-3.2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10204/1879926059.py in <module>
      1 if os.name=='nt':
      2     get_ipython().system('pip install wget')
----> 3     import wget

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wget'
```

Comment: If you run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` to show where Python is being executed from, is it running from within `C:\users\mahmu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38`? There is a possibility that the pip command could be going to a separate Python installation from the python command.

Comment: Yes my python is being executed from 'C:\Users\mahmu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe still same' issue

Comment: How do you later use said `wget`? Is not [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) sufficient?

Comment: To install what is described at https://pypi.org/project/wget/ , the OP should not be using an exclamation point in conjunction with the `pip install` command. By that time the magic install command had been added, and the OP should used `%pip install wget` to install from within the notebook. The magic install command `%pip install` (& related `%conda install` for Anaconda/conda users) was added to overcome the issues that can arise with using the exclamation point. The use of the magic install commands insure the installs occur in the same environment where the kernel that underlies the ...

Comment: <continued> notebook is running. The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues such as that reported by the OP. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the user-friendly, modern magic install commands. See the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues ...

Comment: <continued> sometimes and so use of the magic install variants are current best practice. TL;DR: Use `%pip install wget` and **NOT** an exclamation point.

Answer (score 0):

In **Google-Collab** this code works well:

```
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/6319559/preview.mp3 -O sample_f.mp3
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/256324900/preview.mp3 -O sample_m.mp3
```

But not locally on Windows 10.

In my **Jupyter Notebook** cell this code:

```
# pip install wget
!python -m wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/6319559/preview.mp3 -o sample_f.mp3
!python -m wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/256324900/preview.mp3 -o sample_m.mp3
```

Saves files and returns:

Saved under sample_f.mp3
Saved under sample_m.mp3

OR I tried another way:

I downloaded wget.exe for Windows from here and moved it to PATH-directory. Then code works too:

```
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/6319559/preview.mp3 -O sample_f.mp3
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/256324900/preview.mp3 -O sample_m.mp3
```

Comment: I think the OP was just not understanding how to install from inside the notebook & using outdated methods that can lead to issues. To install what is illustrated at https://pypi.org/project/wget/ , & you properly demonstrate in the first 2/3 of your answer, they should have used `%pip install wget` in the notebook. Likely in that case then the import would have worked because installation would occur in the right environment. I'll add a comment to the OP how this is a case of where the exclamation point in conjunction with an install can lead to an issue and so the magic command was added.

Answer (score -1):

notebook needs to restart to import modules that where installed while the notebook was running. so install the module then restart the notebook

you might get a message like this in Jupiter notebook when you in install a module while running:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: I have restarted the notebook and kernel several times but still the same problem