# pip install Python packages in Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-venv

I would like to create a Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment in VS Code. I want to do different kinds of projects. For that, I have tried to create a virtual environment inside VS Code, where I can download the required packages for the project i.e. TensorFlow, PyTorch... And I want to do those projects in a Jupyter Notebook because I also would like to present them.

1. First, I created a folder in desktop.
   [Step 1]:
   [image]
2. I dragged the folder on VS Code window.
   [Step 2]:
   [image]
3. Created a Jupyter Notebook file called "Project1.ipynb"
   [Step 3]:
   [image]
4. Then Ctrl+Shift+P, and chose "> python:Create Environment" -> Type "venv" and the later Python version that I have as interpreter
   [Step 4]:
   [image]
5. At last, I moved the Jupyter Notebook file to ".venv" virtuasl environment.
   [image]

- So my question is how can I pip install specific python packages to that virtual environment and use them just in that particular virtual environment and not globally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to install package in venv environment in the terminal.

Firstly, active your venv environment by command like `Path\to\venv\active`

[image]

Then you can use command `pip install packageName` to install the python package you want.

Finally, don't forget to choose the python kernel in jupyter.

[image]

Another way is to run codes `! pip install packageName` in cells after choosing the python kernel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I copied and pasted the path name into terminal and activated the virtual environment. And somehow it worked when the path name was in between double quotes.

Comment: The use of the exclamation point with `pip install` isn't reliable in all situations. (See the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more on why that is.) Jupyter added the use of the magic install a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in the environment that is backing the running kernel. To translate that to the example here, **you should be suggesting `%pip install pandas` in modern Jupyter**. See ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about that.

Answer (score 0):

First: Activate the environment that you created.
like in conda, you can activate the environment as "conda activate venv"

Second: after activation you can just do pip install package-name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOQap.png)