# I am getting this error, No module named 'jupyter_dash'

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly-dash

I am new with jupyter and jupyter_dash. Most of this assigment was provided for me and I am to fill in areas. Well I keep getting the "No module name 'jupyter_dash'" error and I have no idea why? I have made sure that I have python3, pip, dash and jupyter installed on my mac.

I don't know what else it could be. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# DASH Framework for Jupyter
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# URL Lib to make sure that our input is 'sane'
import urllib.parse

#TODO: import for your CRUD module
from crud_shelter import Shelter

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    # This element generates an HTML Heading with your name
    html.H1("Module 5 Assignment - Bek Johansson"),
    # This Input statement sets up an Input field for the username.
    dcc.Input(
            id="input_user".format("text"),
            type="text",
            placeholder="input type {}".format("text")),
    # This Input statement sets up an Input field for the password.
    # This designation masks the user input on the screen.
    dcc.Input(
            id="input_passwd".format("password"),
            type="password",
            placeholder="input type {}".format("password")),
    # Create a button labeled 'Submit'. When the button is pressed
    # the n_clicks value will increment by 1. 
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0),
    # Generate a horizontal line separating our input from our
    # output element
    html.Hr(),
    # This sets up the output element for the dashboard. The
    # purpose of the style option is to make sure that the
    # output will function like a regular text area and accept
    # newline ('\n') characters as line-breaks.
    html.Div(id="query-out", style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-line'}),
        #TODO: insert unique identifier code here. Please Note:
    # when you insert another HTML element here, you will need to
    # add a comma to the previous line.
    html.Center(html.B(html.H2('Search and Rescue Candidate Locator'))),
    html.Hr(),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'All', 'value': 'All'},
            {'label': 'Water Rescue', 'value': 'WR'},
            {'label': 'Wilderness Rescue', 'value': 'WR'},
            {'label': 'Disaster Tracking', 'value': 'DT'}
        ],
        value='NYC'
    ),

    
])

# Define callback to update output-block
# NOTE: While the name of the callback function doesn't matter,
# the order of the parameters in the callback function are the
# same as the order of Input methods in the @app.callback
# For the callback function below, the callback is grabbing the
# information from the input_user and input_password entries, and
# then the value of the submit button (has it been pressed?)
@app.callback(
    Output('query-out', 'children'),
    [Input('input_user', 'value'),
     Input('input_passwd', 'value'),
    Input(component_id='submit-val', component_property='n_clicks')]
)
def update_figure(inputUser,inputPass,n_clicks):
    # This is used as a trigger to make sure that the callback doesn't
    # try and connect to the database until after the submit button
    # is pressed. Otherwise, every time a character was added to the 
    # username or password field, an attempt would be made to connect to 
    # the database with an incorrect username and password.
    if n_clicks > 0:
        ###########################
        # Data Manipulation / Model
        # use CRUD module to access MongoDB
        ##########################
        
        # Use the URLLIB to set up the username and password so that they
        # can be passed cleanly to the MongoDB handler.
        inputUser = input("Enter username: ")
        inputPass = input("Enter password: ")

        username = urllib.parse.quote_plus(inputUser)
        password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(inputPass)
        
        ## DEBUG STATEMENT - You can uncomment the next line to verify you
        ## are correctly entering your username and password prior to continuing
        ## to build the callback function.
        print(f'Output: {inputUser}, {inputPass}')

        #TODO: Instantiate CRUD object with above authentication username and 
        # password values

        #TODO: Return example query results. Note: The results returned have
        # to be in the format of a string in order to display properly in the 
        # 'query-out' element. Please separate each result with a newline for
        # readability


# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server()
```

Comment: Did you install `jupyter-dash` package? `pip install jupyter-dash`

Comment: yes, I did. Along with pip3 install jupyter-dash

Comment: Inside your env can you do a `pip list` and see if `jupyter-dash `is there

Comment: Please use `python -m pip install jupyter-dash`, not just `pip install`

Comment: @Irrational_Number thanks for letting me know about pip list and jupyter-dash is on that list :(..

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your notebook through anaconda environment, I suggest you the following

```
import sys

!{sys.executable} -m pip install jupyter_dash
```

Comment: For "if you are running your notebook through anaconda environment", you always should follow that with recommending the user stay with conda as the package manager as they have opted in to that as the main package manager and sticking with Anaconda/conda will lead to much more robust, stable, and portable environments. The modern, user-friendly version is `%conda install -c conda-forge jupyter-dash`, with everything after the magic `%` symbol coming from [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyter-dash). Only fall back to `pip` if absolutely no conda recipe. See ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for the modern, easy to use magic install commands for use inside the notebook instead of that cryptic approach that is no longer best practice. For example, if it `pip` was to be used it would simply be to run`%pip install jupyter_dash` inside a cell in the notebook. Your version involves an import and a more convoluted command to get it to install in the right environment. Magic command does that more clearly.