# "import pattern" does not work but installed succesfully

Tags: python-3.x

I installed python package `pattern` from terminal (MacOS)

```
pip3.11 install pattern
```

and it is successful, however, when I try to import it in my Jupyter notebook as following

```
import pattern
```

There is an error message as follows

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pattern'
```

Any clue? Thank you.

Comment: Normally this means Jupyter isn't using the same python environment that pattern was installed to.  What is the python binary that Jupyter is using and what is the python binary that is associated with pip3.11?

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. Jupyter notebook is in my local machine, also using python 3.11

Comment: If you don't want to figure out how to connect the environments per ewokx, just run in your notebook, `%pip install pattern` and let it install it in the correct environment where the kernel is running that is backing your active notebook. Then restart the notebook kernel and try the import statement. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure installation in the proper environment in use by the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a workable solution. I put the following two lines of Python code before `import pattern`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages")
```

"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages" is the location of `pattern` package in my laptop.

Please let me know if you have further question. Very interesting journey.