# there is an error while installing a library on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to install this lib

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.4.1 tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1 opencv-python mediapip sklearn matplotlib
```

and this what happened

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().system('pip install tensorflow==2.4.1 tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1 opencv-python mediapip sklearn matplotlib')

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2590, in InteractiveShell.system_piped(self, cmd)
   2585     raise OSError("Background processes not supported.")
   2587 # we explicitly do NOT return the subprocess status code, because
   2588 # a non-None value would trigger :func:`sys.displayhook` calls.
   2589 # Instead, we store the exit_code in user_ns.
-> 2590 self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py:129, in ProcessHandler.system(self, cmd)
    125 enc = DEFAULT_ENCODING
    127 # Patterns to match on the output, for pexpect.  We read input and
    128 # allow either a short timeout or EOF
--> 129 patterns = [pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF]
    130 # the index of the EOF pattern in the list.
    131 # even though we know it's 1, this call means we don't have to worry if
    132 # we change the above list, and forget to change this value:
    133 EOF_index = patterns.index(pexpect.EOF)

AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT
```

Comment: As said here: https://www.interviewsvector.com/module-pexpect-has-no-attribute/
maybe you should try update the package and restart the jupyter's kernel

Comment: For modern Jupyter (and not Google Colab), use `%pip install ...`, and not the exclamation point. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure installation in the proper environment in use by the notebook. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) on why to not use an exclamation point for installs.

Answer (score -2):

The error message suggests that there is an issue with the pexpect module, specifically the TIMEOUT attribute.

To resolve this issue, you can try reinstalling the pexpect module using the following command:

```
!pip uninstall pexpect
!pip install pexpect
```

After reinstalling the pexpect module, try running the installation command again:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.4.1 tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1 opencv-python mediapip sklearn matplotlib
```

This should fix the AttributeError related to pexpect.TIMEOUT.

Comment: If this is for modern Jupyter (and not Google Colab), the advice should be to use `%pip install ...`, and not the exclamation point. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure installation in the proper environment in use by the notebook. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) on why to not use `!`.