# ImportError : cannot import name 'spade' from 'spade'

Tags: python, machine-learning, importerror, spade

I'm trying to work with data in Jupyter notebook. I want to use SPADE lib but it gives me an import error.

I tried reinstalling, updating, and restarting the kernel, but it won't work.

```
pip uninstall spade
pip install spade
pip install --upgrade spade
```

[image]

Comment: just `import spade` ?

Comment: from spade import spade , i did , but i wont work , gives the import error

Comment: Where do you get that this is the correct import?

Comment: Jupyter notebook

Comment: You are using outdated approaches and this may be misleading you in thinking you installing properly. It comes down to if the import fails, you aren't installing to the proper environment. If you are installing from in the notebook running where you need it, the syntax should be `%pip uninstall spade` (or `% pip install --upgrade spade`?). Note the use of the magic symbol and **not the exclamation point**. See [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562964/there-is-an-error-while-installing-a-library-on-jupyter-notebook#comment134994376_76563205) that covers the issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at the docs](https://spade-mas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). You should make the import like this:

```
import spade
```

Comment: as you can see, i already do this, gives this  ImportError: cannot import name 'spade' from 'spade'  , in Jupyter notebook

Comment: @Alisi please notice that you have **not** actually shown that `import spade` fails; you have only shown that `from spade import spade` fails, and these are different things. According to the [docs](https://spade-mas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), `import spade` seems to be the correct usage indeed.