# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' problem installing it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to install numpy via terminal and still have the same error. It doesn't seem to recognise it still.

```
import numpy as np

---------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I was expecting to import bumpy but I still get the same error. I tried installing and re installing it by the command pip install numpy

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have finally resolved it as I had to create a virtual environment and then from the terminal inside vscode (btw I'm using a MacBook Pro M2) I had to upgrade pip and then install numpy. Again thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[1], line 1 ----> 1 import numpy as np
```

Because your error message is jupyter style(because of `Cell In[1]`),
try `%pip install numpy` in your cell.

Comment: If you are using Anaconda/conda as your package manager, always choose that primarily. So you run inside your Jupyter notebook's (`.ipynb` file) cell `conda install -c conda-forge nump`, based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy) and best practices for installing from within a Jupyter notebook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) so that **packages are installed into the correct environment that the notebook's kernel is using**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have finally resolved it as I had to create a virtual environment and then from the terminal inside vscode (btw I'm using a MacBook Pro M2) I had to upgrade pip and then install numpy.