# can not install opencv-python using pip in notebook

Tags: python, pip

I am using a cloud GPU computing service where I am given a jupyter environment. I have no problem installing different packages that I want to use. But, for some reason, when I try to install `opencv-python` using the `pip install opencv-python` command, the download speed is incredibly low and it times out. I tried installing it using the `.tar.gz` file with the following code:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'package-name'])

or

!pip install package-name
```

and it gives an error everytime. I wanted to know if there is any way I co0uld install this package from a different server with a better speed or something?

Comment: You can install OpenCV module using Anaconda

Comment: This probably won't solve your issue here but it will be good for you to know for future installs ...if it's official Jupyter you are using (and not Google Colab) than you should be using the magic install commands and not the exclamation point. So `%conda install ...` or `%pip install ...`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357). Keep in mind that pip is more limited, especially when dealing with hardware abilities like CV uses.