# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' I have installed opencv but unable to import cv2

Tags: python, opencv, pip, jupyter

[Screen shot of error "No module named 'cv2' "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfFPQ.png)`

```
!pip install opencv-python
​
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\zunay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.8.0.74)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\zunay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.24.3)
import cv2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 import cv2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Comment: No guarantee this will work; however, did you try running in your notebook `%conda install -c conda-forge opencv`, let it complete (it may take a while), then restart the kernel and try the import. A) Because `anaconda3` in your path, it indiacates you opted to use Anaconda/conda as your **PRIMARY** package manager and so you should always use that package manager first. Only resort to `pip` for anything that doesn't have an Anacaonda/conda recipe. You can see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) the command. B) Current best practice is to always use the added magic install ...

Comment: <continued> commands. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure that the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active notebook file. The exclamation point in conjunction with the install command doesn't do that and so you can have issues. See the second paragraph ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more on why that is. It is best to keep current with practices in modern Jupyter and this is a good gauge for under assessing if the information you are getting is up-to-date. Additionally it is best you learn about environments in relation to Jupyter and how Anaconda can help you manage that well. Plus you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use it as a guide for posting a good post, which this isn't.

Comment: It looks like your versions of pip and python do not agree.  Edit the question and add the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: py -m pip install opencv-contrib-python

Comment: my best guess is that you installed cv2 on a different interpreter than the one you wrote import cv2. is it possible you have virtual environment (different from where you installed) where you ran the code?