# Why I cannot install new programs to an empty environment?

Tags: conda, modulenotfounderror, virtual-environment

I cannot understand the following: while I create a new environment in conda, which is supposed to be empty without programs, when I activate it in jupyter notebook and try to install certain programs it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied (as the program is already downloaded to base environment), but i cannot import the program as it says that the requirement does not exist in this environment.

For example:

!pip install lightgbm xgboost

Requirement already satisfied: lightgbm in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lightgbm) (0.38.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn!=0.22.0 in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0.0 in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn!=0.22.0->lightgbm) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\userid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn!=0.22.0->lightgbm) (2.1.0)

## But when I try to import lightgbm , the following appears

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 import lightgbm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightgbm'

Could you please help me?

Comment: See my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76828966/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cv2-i-have-installed-opencv-but-unable-to#comment135444767_76828966) because: A) you should first always primarily use Anaconda/conda as you seem to have chosen that as your main package manager. B) You should be using the magic install variants of the install commands. The exclamation point w/ install can lead to issues, which may explain your case. So try running in notebook `%conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm` and `%conda install -c conda-forge xgboost` and then restart your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

An empty environment in Conda is actually empty, no Python or anything - so any calls to `pip` or `ipykernel` must be pointing to something outside the environment (i.e., elsewhere on PATH). Moreover, one cannot load an empty environment as a Jupyter kernel - you likely registered another Python instance with the name of your new environment (Jupyter kernel registration names are arbitrary).

At minimum, if you want a Python kernel for Jupyter, then you need to install Python (best if you specify a version) and `ipykernel`:

```bash
conda create -n foo python=3.10 ipykernel
```