# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preprocessing'

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-import, importerror

Ok so I am doing a course on Python ChatBots and there is an off-platform project so I set it up (I am using Jupyter Lab) and I just ran one of the files called training_model.ipynb (It's the Jupyterlab extension for Python) and got the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preprocessing'`
The file exists and is in the same directory as the other 4 other files and any file trying to import another file gets the same error.

Here are the import statements:

```
from preprocessing import num_encoder_tokens, num_decoder_tokens, decoder_target_data, encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data, decoder_target_data, max_encoder_seq_length, max_decoder_seq_length
```

```
from preprocessing import input_features_dict, target_features_dict, reverse_input_features_dict, reverse_target_features_dict, max_decoder_seq_length, input_docs, target_docs, input_tokens, target_tokens, max_encoder_seq_length
from training_model import decoder_inputs, decoder_lstm, decoder_dense, encoder_input_data, num_decoder_tokens, num_encoder_tokens
```

Comment: Can you show the file structure of your project.

Comment: Problem Has been solved I !pip install import_ipynb

Comment: If you are using modern Jupyter and not Google Colab, you'll have a better experience using the modern magic install commands and not in conjunction with the exclamation point. In the notebook, you should be using `%pip install import_ipynb`. In other words, your approach is outdated advice and not current best practice. The exclamation point can cause issue, see the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for why that may be. See ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure that the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active notebook file. The exclamation point in conjunction with the install command doesn't do that and so you can have issues. Here you apparently don't have an issue, but you'll have a better experience adopting the current approach.

Comment: ok thanks for your response but I did find the problem

Comment: The site that gave me the project uses outdated software and techniques I don't know why they don't update their software