# Jupyter Notebook cannot import pyLDAvis.sklearn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, lda, pyldavis

I am using Jupyter Notebook to run python code. I already did the following:

```
!pip install pyldavis
```

I can successfully import pyLDAvis via the following codes:

```
import pyLDAvis
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
```

However, I cannot import pyLDAvis.sklearn via the following codes:

```
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
```

It returns:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[52], line 1
> ----> 1 import pyLDAvis.sklearn_models
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis.sklearn_models'

Why is that and what should I do to deal with it?

Comment: Did you restart the kernel after the install? And for future reference, you are better off using the more modern version of your `pip install` command when running it in the notebook. It isn't the issue here since your main import works after. However, you'll have a better experience going forward and things will work in more places if you adopt current best practices and not outdated guidelines. That command would be `%pip install pyldavis` using the modern magic install command that insures installation occurs in the correct environment where the kernel is running that is underling the ...

Comment: <continued> active notebook. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357) for more about the modern magic install commands. Use of the exclamation point in conjunction with the install commands can sometimes lead to issues. See the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues sometimes.

Comment: You should include details like version information of a package in your post. I think I found your same issue already posted about but I cannot be sure since you aren't providing the details.

Comment: print(pyLDAvis.__version__): 3.4.0 ; print(sklearn.__version__): 1.3.0

Comment: Yes, then the new approach I point out suits your version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there has been a change in how the software handles this pattern.

This issue posted [here](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/issues/251#issue-1705575917) in May of this year (2023) that looks to be the same as yours.

It [links over to a solution](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/issues/245#issue-1618015446) that details how the use of the software has recently developed:

> "pyLDAvis v 3.4.0 no longer has the file sklearn.py in the pip package."
> Replace any logic involving:

```py
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
...
pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare
```

> "with"

```py
import pyLDAvis.lda_model
...
pyLDAvis.lda_model.prepare
```

---

How this was found via troubleshooting:

I went to [the page for the package](https://pypi.org/project/pyLDAvis/) in [the Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/) and clicked on 'GitHub statistics:' on the left side under 'GitHub statistics:'. Then in the 'filters' slot I entered '`pyLDAvis.sklearn`'.
The four that came up as open didn't look too similar to the OP, and so I clicked on the '`7 closed`' tag above the listing. The most recent one listed `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis.sklearn'` looked to be a good match to this post, and so I examined it.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what was kicking up my errors.