# Code that runs fine in jupyter notebook is not used in jupyterlab. how do i fix it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Code that runs fine in jupyter notebook is not used in jupyterlab. how do i fix it?

When I run the code below, I get an error.

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

!pip install matplotlib

!pip install pandas
!pip install numpy


from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import codecs

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pandas as pd

import time
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from datetime import timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')        # Head-less 설정
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GreOZ.png)

I also tried using ChromeDriverManager, but it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Is there another way to use chromedriver in jupyterlab?

Comment: It probably won't help here because it doesn't look like the installation was the issue; however, you'll have a better experience and things will work better on more locations you run Jupyter if you move on to using the **current** magic install commands, `%pip install` in your examples. See more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828917/error-importing-seaborn-module-in-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-utils/76347896#comment134631387_41925357). The exclamation point doesn't insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running, the ...

Comment: <continued> magic variations were added a few years ago to insure the install occurs in the corresponding environment.  See the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues.