# Install only available packages using "conda install --yes --file requirements.txt" without error

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

While installing packages in requirements.txt using Conda through the following command

```
conda install --yes --file requirements.txt
```

If a package in requirements.txt is not available, then it throws a "No package error" such as the one shown below:

> Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
>
> Fetching package metadata: ....
>
> Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching: nimfa ==1.2.3
>
> You can search for this package on anaconda.org with
>
> ```
> anaconda search -t conda nimfa ==1.2.3
> ```

Instead of throwing an error, is it possible to change this behavior such that it installs all the available packages in requirements.txt and throws a warning for those that are not available?

I would like this because, the package nimfa which the error says is not available, can be pip installed. So if I can change the behavior of `conda install --yes --file requirements.txt` to just throw a warning for unavailable packages, I can follow it up with the command `pip install -r requirments.txt` in .travis.yml so TravisCI attempts to install it from either place where it is available.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

I ended up just iterating over the lines of the file

`$ while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement; done < requirements.txt`

*Edit*: If you would like to install a package using pip if it is not available through conda, give this a go:

`$ while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement || pip install $requirement; done < requirements.txt`

*Edit*: If you are using Windows (credit goes to [@Clay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5060792/clay)):

`$ FOR /F "delims=~" %f in (requirements.txt) DO conda install --yes "%f" || pip install "%f"`

Comment: Thanks for this, small hint for anyone using it, make sure your requirements.txt ends with a newline, so that the final package is read in

Comment: Is there a way to also automatically `pip install` packages which are not available using `conda install`, while iterating?

Comment: @delusionX, I've extended the answer.

Comment: I don't get it, why is that `conda install --yes --file requirements.txt` not work by itself?

Comment: @CharlieParker, I think the `--yes` flag only suppresses user interaction but does not ignore errors.

Comment: @TillHoffmann 's solution on a Windows machine: `FOR /F "delims=~" %f in (requirements.txt) DO conda install --yes "%f" || pip install "%f"`  Works very well. Thanks!

Comment: If you've comments in the requirements file, pip complains verbosely (annoying if harmless). A variation of the bash one-liner which ignores comments: `while read req; do if [[ $req != "#"* ]]; then conda install --yes $requirement || pip install $requirement; fi; done < requirements.txt`

Comment: while is not recognised by conda :( what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @A.Papa, the command should be executed in your local shell, e.g. bash.

Comment: Once can add `-c conda-forge` to make sure conda-forge channel is searched as well. So it should be: `FOR /F "delims=~" %f in (requirements.txt) DO conda install -c conda-forge --yes "%f" || pip install "%f"`

Comment: This should be the default behavior.  I can't believe this requires a "one liner bash script" when conda is the recommended way of installing python modules, only using pip as a fallback.

Comment: For those (like me) who aren't familiar with bash scripts, you will only have to modify requirements.txt to the name of your requirements file.

Answer (score 19):

You can do this as mentioned in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704223211/https://www.continuum.io/content/conda-data-science)

Export to .yml file

```
conda env export > freeze.yml
```

To reproduce:

```
conda env create -f freeze.yml
```

Comment: Here is archive.org link
https://web.archive.org/web/20170704223211/https://www.continuum.io/content/conda-data-science

Comment: Looks like when using `conda env create -f file.yml` instead of `conda create -f file.yml` you cannot use the `--yes` flag to skip user prompted installation. Is there a `-y` equivalent for `conda env create`?

Answer (score 4):

Pbms's answer here is the right way to do it, assuming you have an existing environment to copy off of.  Conda is fully capable of installing both Conda packages and pip packages, as listed in `environment.yml`.  I wanted to document the whole process in more detail.  Note that I am using folder-based environments, which is why I added `--prefix [path to environment folder]` to most of the commands.

Say you installed an environment for an existing project to a folder called `env` in the current folder, like this:

```
conda create --prefix ./env
```

You'd generate `environment.yml` for that project's environment like this:

```
conda env export --prefix ./env > environment.yml
```

You'd create a new environment within some other folder by copying `environment.yml` to there and then running this from there:

```
conda env create --prefix ./env --file environment.yml
```

You'd get an already-existing environment to match `environment.yml` by once again copying `environment.yml` to there and then running this from there:

```
conda env update --prefix ./env --file environment.yml --prune
```

With the environment in question active, you'd verify the state of its packages like this:

```
conda list
```

This is an abridged version of what that command might print (note that the pip packages are marked `pypi`):

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pip                       19.2.2                   py37_0
python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
numpy                     1.16.4           py37h19fb1c0_0
pandas                    0.25.1           py37ha925a31_0
pyodbc                    4.0.27           py37ha925a31_0
ibm-db                    3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ibm-db-sa                 0.3.5                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Finally, this is an abridged version of what `environment.yml` might look like (note that the pip packages are listed in their own category):

```
dependencies:
  - pip=19.2.2=py37_0
  - python=3.7.4=h5263a28_0
  - numpy=1.16.4=py37h19fb1c0_0
  - pandas=0.25.1=py37ha925a31_0
  - pyodbc=4.0.27=py37ha925a31_0
  - pip:
    - ibm-db==3.0.1
    - ibm-db-sa==0.3.5
```

Be aware that using Conda and pip together can cause some heartburn because they can unknowingly blow away each other's dependencies.  You are supposed to install all of your Conda packages first and then all of your pip packages afterward, rather than alternating between the two.  If your environment breaks, the official recommendation is to delete and recreate it (from your `environment.yml` file).  For more details, see this guide:

https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

Answer (score 1):

For those looking, I used this as @TillHoffmann 's solution for the fish shell:

```
$ while read requirement; conda install --yes $requirement; end < requirements.txt
```

And

```
$ while read requirement; conda install --yes $requirement;or pip install $requirement; end < requirements.txt
```