# Transfer Pip packages to conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

I am currently using a shared Ubuntu machine which has **python2.7** and multiple packages installed via **pip**.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

$ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

$ pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -----------
asn1crypto                         0.24.0
awscli                             1.11.101
backports-abc                      0.5
...
..
.
```

I want to install **`conda`** and have **`Python 2.7`** and **`Python 3.6`** environment.

How can I install all the packages currently installed (`pip list`) in both conda env (`2.7` and `3.6`) ? I am not concerned with package version. Fine to install the same version or latest version for each package.

Comment: Do you want them installed _via `pip`_ in your conda environment, or installed via `conda` if it exists on `conda` or `conda-forge`, `pip` if not, or installed via `conda` always (generating a recipe on the fly if one doesn't exist)? If you have no idea, I think the second one is likely to be best, but it's your choice.

Comment: Also, "fine to install the same version or latest version…" but not an earlier version, right?

Comment: Prefer to install via conda. And ya, not earlier version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Install same versions

First, get a list of packages installed via pip into a file:

```
pip freeze > packages.txt
```

Then install them using conda inside your two environments:

```
conda install --yes --file packages.txt
```

### Install ignoring versions

`pip freeze` will spit out packages with versions. To remove them, run this instead:

```
pip freeze | sed s/=.*// > packages.txt
```

This way you will more likely succeed in installing them using conda without getting dependency conflicts.

### Anticipating `PackagesNotFoundError`

If you have a lot of packages installed, conda might fail to find some of them. In that case, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802939/install-only-available-packages-using-conda-install-yes-file-requirements-t).

Comment: Assuming my conda python version is 3.6, this will install all packages in 3.6. Is there any steps to copy the same packages to python 2.7 conda env ?

Comment: This is definitely the right thing to do if you want something "semi-automated". It will install all the same versions of the same packages if they all exist on `conda`/`conda-forge`, and give you an error if any of them don't match. (At which point you can edit `packages.txt` to remove some version specifiers, or pull some of the packages out to install separately, etc.)

Comment: @SpandanBrahmbhatt As the answer says, do this same command inside your two environments, and you'll get the same packages (to the extent possible) installed for both.

Comment: @SpandanBrahmbhatt Presumably you have your different Python versions in different conda environments. Switch between them and repeat the second command.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks guys. I will accept the answer once it allows me to do so.

Comment: @SpandanBrahmbhatt One last thing: This answer seems to implicitly assume that you're using a single Anaconda installation with conda environments for 2.7 and 3.6 (rather than two completely separate Anaconda installations). That's exactly what you _should_ be using, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, but if you're not, the details may be slightly different.

Comment: @abarnert I am using the same conda installation. Just creating environment for 2.7.

Answer (score -1):

Downloading conda and installing multiple python versions are given here and also you can find many important commands related to conda. 
https://github.com/Nitish1206/conda_setup_for_ubuntu

Install pip packages in conda via.

```
*while read requirement; conda install --yes $requirement;or pip install $requirement; end < requirements.txt*
```