# How to install all my python modules in single shot

Tags: python, python-3.x, build

I am a beginner in python. I have done a website using ***django, flask, xml, wtforms*** and also i have used some ***API python modules*** too. The website was successfully created and working well in local machine.

But if i want to run in an another python available machine, i am in the need of install all my above mentioned modules manually.

Do we have something similar to gradle, maven or ant which will download/install the required modules during my first run?

Kindly help me.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956741/how-to-install-multiple-python-packages-at-once-using-pip/9956813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to freeze your current local python installations into a requirements.txt file and then install everything in one go in another machine.

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

copy the requirements file into another machine,
install python and then ...

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```