# How do I download multiple dependencies at once in pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have a very big requirements.txt file with many many many dependencies... I have to download and install all of them, so the worst part is the amount. My bandwidth is good, but pip downloads files very slowly, I think there is a limit and I can bypass it using multiple download at once.
So is there a way to download multiple dependencies without the order?

If the limit is cached for each ip, I need a solution by bypassing it with shadow proxies:)

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956741/how-to-install-multiple-python-packages-at-once-using-pip

Comment: No, this is not the solution.

Comment: `pip` does currently not support parallel downloads, since it's a bit more complicated than what it might appear as: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/825 - also make sure that you're actually spending most of your time downloading - and not compiling (which usually is the case). Usually you'd cache these downloads anyway, so the install only happens once-ish. I'd also think that pinning the version requirement also could save some time, since that could potentially eliminate looking up the most recent version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pip` currently doesn't support parallel downloads https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/825

But you can speed up the installation.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

`xargs -n 1 -P 4 pip install < requirements.txt`

Run up to `P` processes at a time; the default is 1. If `P` is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time.

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

Comment: Wouldn't this invoke `pip` with the same requirements file multiple times, each time starting to resolve the dependencies in the same sequence and possibly just downloading each dependency multiple times?

Comment: Instead, a slightly better solution (but which would still potentially download dependencies multiple times) is to slice the requirements file into four different slices, then run those installs in parallel.

Comment: no, the syntax is correct. it'll send one row of requirements.txt to pip at a time with four processes happening at once. i didn't know xargs could do this - cool! my question is if pip can be run in parallel. i was under the impression that it needed to be run serially.