# How to import several libraries with one command from command prompt?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, command-prompt, openpyxl

```
pip install tkinter
pip install PIL
pip install openpyxl
```

I want with one command all of these to be installed on any PC via the command prompt or python shell.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want that? Are you perhaps planning to package an app for easy distribution? If so, look at e.g. PyInstaller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install multiple python packages at once using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956741/how-to-install-multiple-python-packages-at-once-using-pip)

Comment: You cannot install `tkinter` using `pip`.

Comment: when you say PC, do you mean any OS?

Answer (score 1):

You would just do:

```
pip install tkinter PIL openpyxl
```

except that - as acw1668 points out - you cannot install `tkinter` using pip. So that would then be:

```
pip install PIL openpyxl
```

Or you can put them, one per line, in a file called requirements.txt and execute:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

As mentioned by Ceres, you can use the following to put currently-installed packages into the file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

To install from the python prompt, take a look at [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

You're still left with the problem of how to install `tkinter`. Instructions for several different OSs are here: [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

You could combine the answers and use a subprocess to install `python-tk` from within python.

PS Consider pillow over PIL:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: You can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get all installed packages into the file